# Mac/Django error message: "/mercurial/osutil.so: no appropriate 64-bit architecture"

Tags: django, macos, mercurial, 64-bit

I'm new to Macs (and quite new to Django) and I'm setting up an existing Django/MySQL site that uses Mercurial as a site package, on a new Macbook Pro.

All was going well during installation - no error messages. I installed the default versions of most packages from macports.

However when I try runserver, localhost shows the following error message:

```
ImportError at /
.../lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/osutil.so: no appropriate 64-bit architecture (see "man python" for running in 32-bit mode)
```

Please could anyone advise? I've tried typing the following at the terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the correct architecture of Python and/or Mercurial?  What happens when you open up a terminal and type "python"?  Mercurial has two packages for OS X, did you download the appropriate one? (Apple menu->About this mac)

Comment: Did you install another version of Python from Macports or is this the default setup?

Comment: I installed mercurial with the macports default - and it turns out that no, it doesn't run okay. The same "no appropriate 64-bit architecture" appears when I try "hg version" at the command line. 

Python runs okay - though it's version 2.6.1 rather than the latest 2.6.4, for some reason.

What's strange is that all this is running inside a virtualenv. When I leave the virtualenv, mercurial runs fine, and python is version 2.6.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything from my comment checks out, try setting that Prefer-32-bit in an user environment variable instead of at the command line.

Edit this file: ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist

See:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002093-113982

Comment: This solved the problem - thanks. Though I've now got another error message. But it's nice to have made some progress :)

Comment: Well, post away!  I'll help if I can.

Answer (score 3):

I've gotten a similar error and a combination of two things helped me install Mercurial for OS X Lion. I'm running OS X 10.7.3.

First, there is a bug on line 455 of the setup.py script (at least for Mercurial 2.2.1, the version I tried). The line

> version = runcmd(['/usr/bin/xcodebuild', '-version'], {})[0].splitlines()

should be replaced with

> version = runcmd(['/usr/bin/xcodebuild', '-version'], {})[0]

Second, after I installed Mercurial (either by easy_install, Mac OS X binary installer, and compilation), I kept getting the following error message:

> ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/osutil.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/osutil.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

However, after seeing this post, I noticed that

> defaults read com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit

outputs 1 on my system. However, running this command

> defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool no

and then recompiling / installing mercurial resulted in a working executable for me at the end.